# Type Error: invalid color argument & For Looping

Tags: python, for-loop, colors

I'm getting an "invalid color argument" running this code:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, teamcolors[0][1], button_1)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, teamcolors[1][1], button_2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, teamcolors[2][1], button_3)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, teamcolors[3][1], button_4)
```

teamcolors is a list of RGB tuples imported from a csv file that looks like this:

```
(50, 255, 255)
(0, 100, 225)
(200, 200, 0)
(0, 0, 150)
```

and so forth for a total of 15 such lines.

Two questions:

1. how can I avoid the invalid color argument error?
2. how can I loop through the `draw.rect` statements instead of doing them 1-by-1? I can't figure how to iterate on "button_1", "button_2" because it won't let me use a variable for the button numbers therein.

Comment: The csv file is not as above -- it contains 15 rows of 2 RGB tuples each, with the appropriate commas.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a *list* of buttons.

```
buttons = [button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4]

for i in range(4):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, teamcolors[i][1], buttons[i])
```

or better yet

```
for button, color in zip(buttons, teamcolors):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color[1], button)
```

As for why you are getting an invalid color error, what exactly does `teamcolors` look like? *Is* `teamcolors[0][1]` an appropriate `Color` value?

Comment: A list -- I should've thought of that. Thanks. As for the invalid color error, still not sure but it's not happening anymore. The list just contained rows of two tuples each, e.g., [(0, 0, 0), (100, 100, 100)],...

Comment: With `teamcolors[i][1]` or `color[1]`, you aren't passing the entire tuple; you are only passing the green component of the tuple. Use `teamcolors[i]` or `color` as the second argument to `rect`.